# Generate a single report from multiple test stages in .gitlab-ci.yml

Tags: python, testing, report, gitlab-ci, code-coverage

If there exist multiple test scripts in a .gitlab-ci.yml file, for example:

```html
.run_warehouse_tests: &run_warehouse_tests |
  echo "Running tests for Warehouse"
  python -m pytest --durations=0 ./src/unittest -m warehouse --junitxml="junit-test-result-warehouse.xml" -v
  python -m pytest ./src/unittest --cov-report xml --cov=./src/main
  coverage lcov

.run_logistics_tests: &run_logistics_tests  |
  echo "Running tests for Logistics"
  python -m pytest --durations=0 ./src/unittest -m logistics --junitxml="junit-test-logistics.xml" -v
  python -m pytest ./src/unittest --cov-report xml --cov=./src/main
  coverage lcov

.run_packaging_tests: &run_packaging_tests  |
  echo "Running tests for Packaging"
  python -m pytest --durations=0 ./src/unittest -m packaging --junitxml="junit-test-packaging.xml" -v
  python -m pytest ./src/unittest --cov-report xml --cov=./src/main
  coverage lcov
```

how can I generate a single .xml report and coverage report that would cover all tests. The above examples are just for reference and I would like to avoid creating multiple .xml files and group all tests into one.